# defining custom rules for code styles .clang-format in Clion

Tags: linux, ubuntu, clang, clang-format

I am using the `clang-format` plugin with Clion on Ubuntu. The way I generated the .clang-format is using

```sh
bash $ clang-format -style=Google -dump-config > .clang-format
```

This generate a YAML file which contained the flags for the code rules and they are pre-defined. Now I want to add my own custom rules. For instance, if there is an equality test, constant should be at the left hand side.

Is there any way to incorporate our custom rules in a .clang-format YAML file?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe I did not understand it, but can't you just take the dump file as a starting point and edit it?

Comment: @PhilippClaßen sorry for late response. No, the YAML file generated suing  $ clang-format -style=Google -dump-config > .clang-format  contained only pred-defined rules which we can set true or false. I cannot figure out how can I add my own custom rules there.

Comment: @PhilippClaßen I'm working for a company where they have strict coding style guidelines for C++ but I have no automatic tool to validate them

Comment: Ah, got it. I missed that you wanted to extend the existing functionality by adding custom rules.

Comment: yes right now I can "refactor my source code with clang format" in Clion but the rules are pred-defined